# code optimization histogram c++ from matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization

```
LIBIQTOOL_API void Hist(std::vector<double>input, std::vector<double> bins, std::vector<double>& histogram)
{
    double minY = *std::min_element(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
    double maxY = *std::max_element(std::begin(input), std::end(input));
    std::vector<double> edges;    
    edges.push_back(-1 * std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    for (int i = 0; i < bins.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        edges.push_back(bins[i] + 0.0100 / 2);
    }
    edges.push_back(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());


    //histC

    histogram.resize(edges.size() - 1);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < edges.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if ((edges[j] < input[i]) && (input[i] <= edges[j + 1]))
            {
                histogram[j] = histogram[j] + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    histogram[histogram.size() - 1] = histogram[histogram.size() - 1] + histogram[histogram.size() - 2];
    histogram.pop_back();
}
```

the input vector is size 3,000,000++ and the number of bins is ~7000.
I have taken Matlab's Hist() function and created the code I need in c++.
however it take very long to run, can you see more optimizations for runtime which can be done here?
I did:
a. break when you find the bin to place the current number
b. use openMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible optimizations:

- do not pass your input data by value, but by const reference
- Do not check lower bound, only upper bound for each bin when doing the linear search for the correct bin.
- Alternatively: Since your bins are ordered monotonously and there are no gaps, do a binary search for the correct bin, not a linear search.

The last one should give you the greatest gains, the others are more trivial to implement.

Btw the way you fill the edges vector looks strange.

Comment: isn't there a way just to get the index of the bin without any search?

Comment: Only if you can find an analytical function to match values to bins, such as if all bins have the same width.

Comment: they are of the same width.-Inf 0.00500000000000000 0.0150000000000000 0.0250000000000000 0.0350000000000000 0.0450000000000000 0.0550000000000000 0.0650000000000000 0.0750000000000000 0.0850000000000000 0.0950000000000000 0.105000000000000 0.115000000000000 0.125000000000000 0.135000000000000 0.145000000000000 0.155000000000000 and so on,,,

Comment: Well, then it's bin_index = floor((value - lower_bound) / bin_width). With some code to check for inf/-inf inclusion.

Comment: int index = floor((input[i] - (0.0100 / 2)) / 0.01); ??

Comment: With the values from your comment its int index = (int)floor((input[i] + 0.005) / 0.01); if (index < 0) index = 0; if (std::vector<double>::size_type(index) >= histogram.size()) index = histogram_size() - 1; // The plus in + 0.005 is from the double minus, your lowest bound is -0.005. Also note that you should really do these boundary checks in the value domain, not the bin index domain, to avoid integer overflows. I did it here in integer for simplicity.